# Android, Xamarin: After changing target framework: "Handle must be valid, paramter name: Instance"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

for quite some time now we are having a major issue with our app. As of August the 1st, Google ist requiring us to have the target framework set to be 8.0. However, this causes a major problem. Whenever I am doing this, our app preferences class completely break down. Though some prefs still work, others (always the same one) will crash saying: Handle must be valid, parameter name: instance."

This happens on this very little line of code:

```
    public int getNumberOfNews()
    {
       return mSharedPrefs.GetInt(NUMBEROFNEWS, 0);
    }
```

All Prefs look like exactly this, but some work and some crash. Why is this the case? We need to be able to fix this issue immediately. Setting the target framework for anything BELOW 8.0 everything works fine. But then we wouldn't be able to update our app on the google play store...

Please help.

EDIT:

I have just noted that Prefs ALWAYS crash when NOT using "compile using SDK version" as target framework. What could that mean? :(

Comment: mSharedPrefs must be instantiated in a class and both in on create (just a  suggestion of possible crash). Are you sure it is not a bug already reported for Xamarin?

Comment: I dont know, I didnt find anything. Ofc I am instantiating the class in OnCreate. It always worked, but stopped now. Please also see my edit.

Comment: Because you need to tell which SDK version to use see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Comment: I am thinking is anyway a bug in GetInt by  android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt

Comment: @user3344236 i tried using putstring or getstring but the issue remaind the same :(

Comment: I think maybe something on interface (instantiate fragments or else) can crash the app. Try to put breakpoints in all methods calls to fragments.... Maybe this will help you (debug step by step) to catch the error. Is NUMBEROFNEWS defined  anyway with a default value somewhere in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many, many tries with no luck I've come up with a workaround:

At the beginning of my app I am instantiating a singleton that holds all preferences and only call this singleton. this worked and i an super happy :)